# How to share objects between different functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make it so that if a user activates `test`, it will display a test menu in the chatroom and if that same user posts a reaction on any message, it will delete that test menu:

```
import discord, asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith('test'):
        menu = await client.send_message(message.channel, "test menu")

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if user == message.author:
        await client.delete_message(menu)

client.run('ClientToken')
```

However, the code is not reading the objects like `message.author` or `menu` from the other function.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a dictionary to hold the message and author values.

```
test = {'message': None, 'author': None}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith('test'):
        menu = await client.send_message(message.channel, "test menu")
        test['message'] = menu
        test['author'] = message.author

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if user == test['author']:
        await client.delete_message(test['message'])
```